# Adding Farsi characters to AntiXSS library

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, security, antixsslibrary

I'm using the AntiXSS as the default engine for my Asp.Net MVC website. The problem is, it encodes Farsi characters like "راهنما". I'm not an expert in security but I think these characters are fine and won't cause a problem for my website. I was wondering if I could add them to the white-list of this library to let them render normally not as encoded characters. (same text above shown as "`&#1585;&#1575;&#1607;&#1606;&#1605;&#1575;`")

Comment: Simply use HttpUtility to encode strings. It is just as secure because it does not leave dangerous characters unencoded.

Comment: @usr the problem with that approach is that I have to manually encode every single piece of user output. That way I may miss somewhere. Using AntiXSS library ensures that all the output is going through a white list instead of a black list